# Wider navigator columns in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I'd like to style my navigator columns in a Highstock chart to take up more horizontal space (be less 'gappy') but I can't seem to find the settings to do it.

[image]

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle with your data? I just tried, looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ry68wmbk/  Anyway, try to play around with `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ry68wmbk/1/

Comment: This was the clue I needed thank you. Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control width of the item using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`, for example:

```
navigator: {
  series: {
    type: 'column',
    pointPadding: 0,
    groupPadding: 0
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ry68wmbk/1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use following in your chart config:

```
   spacingBottom: 0,
    spacingTop: 0,
    spacingLeft: 0,
    spacingRight: 0,
    margin:0,
    padding:0
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the navigator column widths are automatically calculated based on the values of `pointPadding` and `groupPadding`. This worked for me:

```
navigator: {
    series: {
        type: 'column',
        pointPadding: 2,
        groupPadding: 2
    },
},
```

[image]